# using gestureoverlayview with scrollview problem

Tags: android

I have scrollview in that i have tableview and in that I have gestureoverlayview ....my problem is when I do any gesture horizontally it works fine but when I do any gesture vertically the scrollview start moving ...the event get captured by scrollview ... I tried following code but it dint work out

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("m touched");
    if(ev.equals(sEvent)){
        System.out.println("in touched2");

        return overlay.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }else{
    return scl.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?